# Should I say "go out" or "go outside"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm in a meeting and I want to say that I'm leaving the room for a minute (for example to go to the bathroom or for some other reason). Which sentence is better and why:

I'm going out for a minute.

I'm going outside for a minute.

Answer (score 1):

In these sentences, both out and outside have been used as adverbs. If we look at these sentences from the angle of the situation stated, it is clear that the speaker is not going far way from the building but going somewhere around the building or the room he is in. For this purpose, he will say, "I am going outside for a minute".
Otherwise, he will say, "I am going out for a minute".  But I think "a minute or a short time" is not enough to go away from the building, he can also use "out" in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. "Out" and "Outside" usually mean the same thing when used as prepositions. "Outside" is more precise when used as an adverb. It usually depends on the situation.

For eg. I am going to paint on the outside (of the house).